# Prevent lines from being connected in Altair Chart

Tags: python, altair

I want to plot two lines in an altair plot.
One of the lines does not have values for some x-values.
Currently, the line fragments are being connected, but i need them to show as disconnected.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import altair as alt

dd = {'x': np.arange(8),
     'group': [1,1,1,2,2,2,1,1],
     'y': [5,1,2,4,2,1,4,5]}

df = pd.DataFrame(dd)

alt.Chart(df).mark_line(point=True).encode(x='x:N', y='y', color='group:O')
```

current output:

[image]

desired output:

[image]

How can i disconnect the line fragments of group '1'?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like what you want is to [impute](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/transform/impute.html) a null value. You can do this using an impute transform within the encoding:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import altair as alt

dd = {'x': np.arange(8),
     'group': [1,1,1,2,2,2,1,1],
     'y': [5,1,2,4,2,1,4,5]}

df = pd.DataFrame(dd)

alt.Chart(df).mark_line(point=True).encode(
    x='x:N',
    y=alt.Y('y', impute=alt.ImputeParams(value=None)),
    color='group:O'
)
```

[image]